# Data security while MacBook is on lock screen

Tags: macbook-pro, security, filevault

I've recently sent my MacBook (running on Catalina) to repair by a licensed Apple service provider. The whole thing was simple (replacing one key cap) and took about 5 minutes or so. But I forgot to shut down the MacBook and only put it on lock screen. I have FileVault enabled.

Is it possible for my data to be breached in that scenario? My understanding is that FileVault only protects your data by requiring you to enter your login password when you start up the drive. It sounds like once you have logged into the computer (even if it is now on lock screen), the data is decrypted and vulnerable to unauthorized access?

Comment: Do you have *File Sharing* enabled in System Preferences > Sharing?

Comment: If they were NSA, they might be able to do some fancy stuff like 'cold boot attack' or '(Thunderbolt) DMA attack'.